# Set Active class in Navbar Dynamically

Tags: php, include, navbar

Initially I had a bootstrap navbar, and I hard coded the navbar code into every one of my html files. I set the active class of the tab of whatever page the user was currently viewing manually like this:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="map.html">View Map</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Submit Document</a><li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

This worked fine, but I realized it was bad practice to repeat code like this, so I put the navbar code into a separate file, turned all my html files into php files, and used the php include statement to load the navbar in each page. I then used JavaScript in an attempt to dynamically set the active class. However, I can't get the active class to show at all when clicking on my tabs.

```
<head>
    <link href="../css/navbar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<!-- JAVASCRIPT TO TOGGLE ACTIVE CLASS-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
  $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
</script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <!-- Mobile collapse-->
        <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage.html">
      <img src="../images/pksoilogo.png" id="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> <!-- Mobile collapse/Dropdown-->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="homepage.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="map.php">View Map</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Submit Document</a><li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Any thoughts on how to correct the JavaScript to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT* - Sorry, I hadn't read the part about you wanting a Javascript fix. Hopefully someone can give a JS solution to your problem soon enough!

Here's one way to go about it.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'homepage.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="homepage.php">Home</a></li>
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'about.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'map.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="map.php">View Map</a></li>
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'index.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="index.php">Submit Document</a></li>
  <li <?php if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'contact.php') echo 'class="active"' ?>><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Obviously that's not the cleanest of ways, but it's quite easy. You could also make a function that you could call to make it look a bit better.